# How to literally exchange two files on different partitions?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-transfer

I have two very big database files (more than 100 GB each). They are stored on different partitions.

Now I have to exchange these files, that is moving *FileA* from *PartitionA* to *PartitionB* and *FileB* from *PartitionB* to *PartitionA*.

Problem is, that I don't have enough free space on one of both partitions to move them one after another.

So what I am looking for is a way to literally exchange them, simultaneously.
I need them to be exchanged physically, as the one partition is on a hard drive and the other one is on a solid state disc.

It does not have to be super save. I have backups of the files for the case it fails (but it takes some time to restore them).

Comment: Absolute easiest way? Don't move the files, but instead use a directory junction to exchange the directories: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx only caveat is that you have to do it on the directory above file rather than the file itself, but the mklink command can be used to do it. Rename the directory on partition A then create a link pointing to partition B.

Comment: I need them to be exchanged physically, as the one partition is on a hard drive and the other one is on a solid state disc.

Comment: Use an additional storage device or cloud service.  Another option: databases tend to be very compressible.  Split each database into multiple subsets and compress each one.  You can accomplish that with limited free space on each partition.  That will leave more free space.  Swap pieces between partitions a pair at a time until they're all moved.  Then reassemble the databases.